# Filtering out empty strings from nested arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
let arr = [
      ["do you ever", "have you ever", "worried"],
      ["another", ""],
      ["about"],
      ["the notion"],
      ["that"],
      ["did you ever"],
      [""]
];
```

I need to remove empty strings from the nested arrays and nested arrays that became empty as a result. e.g.,

```js
[ ["do you ever", "have you ever", "worried"],
  ["another"],
  ["about"],
  ["the notion"],
  ["that"],
  ["did you ever"]
];
```

Comment: Better if you mention the expected output as well!!!

Comment: Yeah! @Pixier Please add expected output for a case or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another implementation:

```js
let arr = [
      ["do you ever", ,"","have you ever", "worried"],
      ["another", ""],
      ["about"],
      ["the notion"],
      ["that"],
      ["did you ever"],
      [""]
];
arr = arr.map(a => a.filter(e => e !== "")).filter(e=> e.length !== 0)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like the following way:

```js
let arr = [
      ["do you ever", "have you ever", "worried"],
      ["another", ""],
      ["about"],
      ["the notion"],
      ["that"],
      ["did you ever"],
      [""]
];
arr = arr.map(i => i.filter(i => i.trim())).filter(i => i.length);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This is not working with `let arr = [
      ["do you ever", "have you ever", "worried"],
      ["another", ""],
      ["about"],
      ["the notion"],
      ["that"],
      ["did you ever"],
];`

Comment: @Pixier, well there could be some other scenario if I solve that!!!

Comment: @Mamun then you'll have to check for empty strings " " inside  nested arrays

Comment: @AkashSarode, yes you are right, updated the answer, thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it all your arrays (parent and sub arrays) can reduce in size. Using `Array#filter` alone is impossible and `Array#map` isn't going to reduce the size of an array.

You can use either `Array#reduce` or `Array#flatMap` for this.

I'd go for the latter in this case. It allows you to unnest sub arrays produced during an iteration. This means that you can grow an array with `Array#flatMap`:

```
[1, 2].flatMap(n => [n, n]);
//=> [1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Meaning you can empty an array too:

```
[1, 2].flatMap(n => []);
//=> []
```

Both examples cannot be done with `Array#map`.

So we can use to both transform the elements of an array *and* transform the array itself (i.e. size gets bigger or smaller):

```js
const xs = [
      ["do you ever", "have you ever", "worried"],
      ["another", ""],
      ["about"],
      ["the notion"],
      ["that"],
      ["did you ever"],
      [""]
];

console.log(

  xs.flatMap(ys => {
    const zs = ys.filter(y => y !== "");
    return zs.length > 0 ? [zs] : [];
  })

)
```

Answer (score 0):

By the combination of map and filter, you can achieve that;

*I assume the arr only contains arrays and that arrays contain strings. Otherwise, there should be a type check.*

```
let arr = [
  ["do you ever", "have you ever", "worried"],
  ["another", ""],
  ["about"],
  ["the notion"],
  ["that"],
  ["did you ever"],
  [""]
];

arr.map(items => items.filter(_item => _item.length > 0)).filter(i => i.length > 0);
```